# JMETER: how to create a group of N threads where N is the number of lines in a file

Tags: java, csv, jmeter, performance-testing, threadgroup

I have the following test plan:

[image]

I want to have 1 thread on each line of csv file.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: for(....) loop sound familiar?

Comment: Can you elaborate? In plain Java you'd just `FIles.lines().parallel()` but you mention jmeter...

Comment: @Xoce 웃 Пepeúpa it shiuld be executed in parallel

Comment: @fge yep, I need solution for jmeter

Comment: Are you asking how to create a group of N threads where N is the number of lines in a file?

Comment: @Brandon you are right

Comment: I had this issue too, but gave up. Instead, I defined a parameter "totalThreads" on plan level with hard-coded value (based on spreadsheet size), and use it in the thread group definition as `${totalThreads}`. At least I can manage it in one place.

Comment: So you want JMeter to automatically pick the no. of rows in CSV and create no. of threads equal to no. of rows in csv? If that is your requirement then it is not possible with current jmeter capabilities.  A workaround could be that first you run a threadgroup (having beanshell code that can read the number of rows. Store that into a variable). After that you can use it. There is not straight forward solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you will need to count lines in CSV file **before** jmeter starts, like:

1. In JMeter define "Number of threads" using [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function like

   ```
   ${__P(threads,)}
   ```
2. You can pass `threads` property value via `-J` command-line argument like

   ```
   jmeter -Jthreads=60 ....
   ```
3. You can use your operating system commands to count lines in CSV file like:

   - for MS Windows use "for" loop as  Xoce 웃 Пepeúpa suggests, like create  i.e. `runtest.bat` file like:

     ```
     setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
     set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE.CSV | find /C ":""

     for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set threads=%%a

     jmeter.bat -Jthreads=%threads% -n -t test.jmx ...
     ```
   - for Linux/Unix you can use [wc](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_wc.htm) and [awk](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_awk.htm) commands combination and run JMeter like:

     ```
     ./jmeter -Jthreads="$(wc -l PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE.CSV | awk {'print $1'})" -n -t test.jmx
     ```

Theoretically Linux way should be suitable for OS X as well.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them

Comment: in logs I see:    

*jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 0 threads for group Thread Group.  
jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 0 ramp-up 0 perThread NaN delayedStart=false*